# Adding host file to docker container - from Dockerfile

Tags: svn, ssh, docker, dockerfile

It's my First 2 hours using docker.  I've imported a linux image from centos 4.0.6 (project requirement).

I realise there are other questions that describe copying files from host to docker container, but I want to copy a file from host to container during the creation of the  container - e.g. via Dockerfile command.

My reason for attempting this is as follows:

So my Dockerfile has to checkout some code from an svn server and build then execute the compiled code.

The svn connection uses svn+ssh protocol.  As the user in the container is root, I add the appropriate ssh user to the ~/.subversion/config file, and configure no StricthostKeyChecking.

In my docker

in my dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "[tunnels]" > ~/.subversion/config
RUN echo "ssh = ssh -l mysvnuser" >> ~/.subversion/config
RUN echo -e "Host svnserver.lan\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> /root/.ssh/config
RUN svn co svn+ssh://svnserver.lan/svn/bananas/branches/Ti_2.4 bananas
...
```

I'm getting the following svn authentication error:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'svnserver.lan,192.168.1.8' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

So I know that I need to add mysvnuser's id_rsa in order to solve this, but will svn use id_rsa from /root/.ssh or /home/mysvnuser/.ssh ?

Has anyone successfully transferred a file from the docker host to a container via the Dockerfile?

Comment: Have a look at the ADD and COPY instructions in aDockerfile, see the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the directory containing your docker file, you simply add the file that you want to transfer to the container like so:

```
ADD name-of-file.extension /
```

This will place the file in the root of your container, change the `/` to whatever you want in order to put the file in the appropriate location.

Comment: I tried that - e.g. with ADD /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa /
It didn't work.

Comment: I missed the "In the directory containing your docker file" bit, works!